# How to escape String data in Sql

Tags: sql

This is what I have

```
String LabelText= SemiLabel.getText(); //the value in the label is "Year 1 Sem I";
Connection conn=dbc.connect() ;
```

This is what I have

```
String LabelText= SemiLabel.getText(); //the value in the label is "Year 1 Sem I";
Connection conn=dbc.connect() ;
Resultset rs =conn.createStatement().excuteQuery("Select SchoolOfMusic, Semester FROM Units, registeredUnitsTable WHERE Semester = " +LabelText)
```

The problem is am getting an syntax error near `'1 Sem I'` at line one.

How can I escape it in sql to get `'Year 1 Sem I'` and not `'1 Sem I'`, am comparing my data received with the one the database Column Semester.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify your text as a single SQL literal value in the query. The simple way is to surround the text in single quotes:

```
Resultset rs =conn.createStatement()
  .excuteQuery("Select SchoolOfMusic, Semester FROM Units, registeredUnitsTable WHERE Semester = '"
     + LabelText + "'")
```

The better way is to let the driver handle it using a placeholder and calling `setObject()`.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to insert the string to the query:

```
Connection conn=dbc.connect();
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("Select SchoolOfMusic, Semester FROM Units, registeredUnitsTable WHERE Semester = ?");
ps.setString(1, LabelText);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: this is the way better solution. it's not pentratable by sql injection and robust against strings containing quotes.

Comment: Ok fine copy that